# Save Embedded Zip file(OLEObject) to disk

Tags: excel, vba

I have embedded zip file in an excel file, when i copy the file and paste into any drive. The zip file is not opening and getting the following message (Windows cannot open the folder. the compressed(zipped) folder 'Filepath' is invalid). 
I also tried OLEObject.Verb, but it opening in temp folder and leave the temp folder explorer open in all the time.

How to copy the zip file and close the temp folder explorer?

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Nope, anywhere in the drive.